# Do the subordinate matrix norms satisfy $\|AB\|=\|BA\|$? Explain.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

**Do the subordinate matrix norms satisfy $\|AB\|=\|BA\|$? Explain.**

I know that $\|A\|_1=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$ and $\|A\|_2=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$, but I already tried with these subordinate matrix rules and I do not reach equality. I'm thinking badly? Or is this result true for a different standard than the one I mentioned? Thank you very much.

Comment: would you like to include your working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example,
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \\
B &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}$$
and any matrix norm (subordinate or not) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\left(\text{or }\mathbb{C}^2\right)$.

Comment: If $B$ and $A$ are symmetric, then this identity holds for the operatornorm induced by the euclidian norm, because $\|AB\|=\|(AB)^T\| =\|B^T A^T\| = \|BA\|$.